# Check if layer exists in QGIS Project using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, qgs

In QGIS, what is the simplest python code (least possible) to verify if a particular layer is PRESENT or ABSENT in the Map Layers list?

*NOTE:* The script shouldn't trip an error IF the layer is ABSENT.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
len(QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('the_Map_Layer_in_question')) != 0
```

`True`if layer exists, otherwise `False`

Comment: note that you could avoid the `len(...) != 0` and just directly test the returned list, eg `if QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('the_Map_Layer_in_question'):`

Answer (score 12):

### For QGIS 3.x versions

In QGIS 3.x the functionality of `QgsMapLayerRegistry` has been moved to [`QgsProject`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html), so in PyQGIS 3 you need this:

```py
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("the_Map_Layer_in_question")
exist = True if layers else False
print(exist)
```

---

**References:**

- [QGIS API Documentation](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
 boolean = False
 layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
 for name, layer in layers.iteritems():
     if layer.name() == ('the_Map_Layer_in_question'):
         boolean = True    
 # if the map layer exists boolean == True, if it doesn't boolean == False
```